# Adding search function to existing Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have scoured the internet for the ability to add the search box function to an existing google map for v3. All attempts at using API v2 do not work anymore. My project: Simply allow site visitors to type in their address in a google search box and then have a place marker placed at location. Link to my map:http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl

Ultimately, what I am going to do is draw a polygon around the border of the services areas and shade it a certain color. Then, I want to allow a site visitor to be able to type in their address to see if they fall within the service territory of this company. I am very new, so any help with this would be very much appreciated. I have tried all the examples in the API, but there isn't one for V3, and I have troubles adding the code to my existing map and making it work.

Comment: please define "service areas". Also show us the working V2-examples and describe what especially you cannot get working.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the Geocoding Service of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests

Example here:

> https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple